# Hibernate saveorupdate method does not insert multiple rows using for loop

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to insert multiple rows in the Database. I am calling the hibernate `saveorupdate` method inside a for loop for inserting multiple rows in the table. But only row gets inserted below is the code

```
for(int i=1; i<=noofrows;i++) // value of noofrows is fetched from jsp
  saveintoDB(employeeData);
```

Below is the DAO method

```
public EmployeeData saveintoDB(EmployeeData employeeData)  throws Exception{
    Session session = null;
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        session.saveOrUpdate(employeeData);

        tx.commit();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return employeeData;
}
```

The employeeData object has empid as the primary key. Does hibernate allows only one row to be inserted at a time or do we have to make changes for empid property in `EmployeeData.hbm.xml`?

Comment: Please post complete code how employeeData is being instantiated. A new instance of employeeData should be created within the loop.

Comment: what is this `saveintoDB()`method? It has no args so it's different from `saveintoDB(EmployeeData employeeData)`

Comment: saveintoDB(employeeData) updated

Comment: you call your `saveintoDB(...)` methods on the same object in the loop. SO you try to insert lines which have the same primary key.

Comment: does only one copy of object gets saved in the database in Hibernate even though a loop used? @jhamon: Can't we insert multiple rows with a single object? As primary key is auto generated every time a new record is inserted. How could we save multiple times using the same object?

Comment: If you use your method on the same object, this one always have the same primary key so it can be inserted only once. If you want to insert multiple rows, you have to change the primary key before each insert.

Comment: Even if your primary key is a `Serial`type in your DB, if each  of your `EmployeeData` has the same key in your java code, it won't work. Show us how is instantiated your `employeeData` and what type your primary key is.